# Python bug regarding attribute

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I recently coded the following:

```
class Neural_Network(object):
def _init_(self):
    self.inputLayerSize = 2
    self.outputLayerSize = 1
    self.hiddenLayerSize = 2

    # Weights
    self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputLayerSize,\
                             self.hiddenLayerSize)
    self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenLayerSize,\
                             self.outputLayerSize)

    def forward(self, X):

        self.z2 = np.dot(X, self.W1)
        self.a2 = self.sigmoid(self.z2)
        self.z3 = np.dot(self.a2, self.W2)
        yHat = self.sigmoid(self.z3)
        return yHat

    def sigmoid(self, z):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
```

Now, the problem is when I am doing the following: -

```
NN = Neural_Network()
```

and

```
yHat = NN.forward(X)
```

I am getting the following error: -

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 yHat = NN.forward(X=0.9)
>
> AttributeError: 'Neural_Network' object has no attribute 'forward'

I am new to Python but really interested to learn. Can you please tell me what I am ding wring here?

By the way I am doing this in jupyter-notebook

Best

Comment: I fixed your indentation in my edit - does it work now that `forward()` is within the scope of your class definition?

Comment: oops, fixed again

Comment: @JacobIRR and by editing the question we now will _never_ know, if the problem was by wrong indentation on behalft of the original code, the copy&pasted version into this Q or by you editing it. Simply do not edit code indentation.

Comment: @Alex I did. he scoped all 1 in. Do _you_ know if the OPs code looks like that? Or if he miscopy/pasted?

Comment: @PatrickArtner if you click the link "edited X minutes ago" you can see the edits

Comment: I've rolled back to the original (incorrect) indentation. Let the OP fix his own indentation, or you risk invalidating the question.

Comment: @JacobIRR I know, and I did look into the edit history. My point is: you do not know if his sourcecode looks like what he posted as questions _here_ (although the error message lends to it being a problem). By reformatting it you eleminate the source of the problem. I am all for formatting code, but not if it is the source of the problem.

Comment: word, thanks for the tip! @PatrickArtner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problesms:

1. It's `__init__` (double underscore) not `_init_`.
2. Your `forward` and `sigmoid` functions are defined in the `__init__` method instead of in the `class` scope.

Try this:

```
class Neural_Network(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def forward(self, X):
        ...

    def sigmoid(self, z):
        ...
```

Comment: Ah this block indentation principle requiring to double check code after any copy-paste to ensure the tabs have been correctly reproduced. I wish "Guido" did use usual brackets instead of inventing the oblate wheel.